# Java string inside string

Tags: java

Write a program that asks the user to enter two Strings, and prints the number of times that the second String appears within the first String. For example, if the first String is "banana" and the second is "an", the program prints 2.

Below is my code so far

```
public class Assignment4 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);

//Prompt the user to enter a string
        System.out.println("Enter a word:");
        String input = answer.nextLine();

//Ask the user to enter a second String
        //look at index method of string
        System.out.println("Enter another word:");
        String input2nd = answer.nextLine();
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
            if(input.charAt(i) == input2nd.charAt(0)) {
                counter++;

            } 
        }
        System.out.println(input2nd + " appears " + counter + " times.");
```

When I type banana into first string, and second string is "an", the only thing come up is number 3, and it is for character a which appear 3 time, but not two as it suppose to only be 2 "an"

Comment: Use [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int))

Answer (score 0):

Consider this trick I learned years ago:

1. replace the searched word in the original word by emptychars...
2. get the diff between the length of both... searched chars and the original with replaced
3. divide that by the len of the searched word...

```
private static void searchString() {
Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);
// Prompt the user to enter a string
System.out.println("Enter a word:");
String input = answer.nextLine();

// Ask the user to enter a second String
// look at index method of string
System.out.println("Enter another word:");
String input2nd = answer.nextLine();
String a = input.replace(input2nd, "");
int counter = (input.length() - a.length()) / input2nd.length();
System.out.println(input2nd + " appears " + counter + " times.");
}
```

with the input **banana** and **an** will print 2